# Python MultiProcessing Updating Global Variable

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm having an issue where I try to kick off multiple processes using multiprocessing, and try to have each process update a global dict object.

Code is:

```
import multiprocessing

jobs = []

master_dict = {}

def worker_function(list1, id):
    master_dict[str(id)] = {}

    for i in list1:
        #
        # using pymssql here to get a cursor of rows from a SELECT query
        #
        master_dict[str(id)][i] = []

        for row in cursor:
            master_dict[str(id)][i].append(row)

    return

def multi_function():
    for i in list2:
        my_proc = multiprocessing.Process(name='multi_process', target=worker_function, kwargs={'list1': session['something'], 'id': i})

        jobs.append(my_proc)
        my_proc.start()

    for job in jobs:
        job.join()
return master_dict{}
```

When I print what is being appended along the way, I do see that data is being added to master_dict, however once it returns, it is simply {} .

Is this an issue with the multiple processes attempting to update the same variable?  I know with multiple threads this is an issue, for thread safety.

Any suggestions would be incredibly helpful!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot share state between processes like this. The `multiprocessing` module contains a [number of different approaches](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) to doing this.